# Get the Difference between 2 Times

Tags: java, android, date, date-difference

i'm trying the get the Difference between 2 dates time..
i have an arraylist, each object contains data of type Date..

My Questions are:
1) is using Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) ... etc the best way to get the current date & Time
2) should i fill manually the data in variable of Date, as follows:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setMinutes(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE));
currentDate.setHours(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR));
currentDate.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
currentDate.setMonth(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH));
currentDate.setYear(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

3) How to get the Difference between the currentDate and the an old date i have
is it like `currentDate - oldDate` and what about the "AM_PM" issue, should i do this function manually?

Comment: What if i'm using the Time() as i have defined all my variables as Time not Date, i THE SimpleDateFormate is working with Date only, can i get the difference between the 2 variables on Time without converting it to Date, and to convert if i have to??

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

**1) is using Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) ... etc the best way to get the current date**

JavaDoc from java.util.Date empty constructor:

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the
>   time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond.

**3) How to get the Difference between the currentDate and the an old date i have is it like currentDate - oldDate and what about the "AM_PM" issue, should i do this function manually?**

```
Date oldDate = ...
Date currentDate = new Date();
long dt = currentDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

1) To get the current date:

```
Date = new Date();
```

2) TO set manually a Date it is better to work with a Calendar.

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
// ... and so on
Date date = c.getTime();
```

3) to calculate the distance in ms between two dates.

```
Date d1 = ....;
Date d2 = ....;
long distance = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, variable `now` below is current date.

```
String givenDate = "03/11/2015";

          SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
          try {
                 Date date = (Date)dateFormat.parseObject(givenDate);
                 Date now = new Date();
                 System.out.println(date);
                 System.out.println(now);
                 int diffInDays = (int)( (now.getTime() - date.getTime()) 
                    / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) );

                 System.out.println(diffInDays);

          } catch (ParseException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

You can choose any format and add time or AM/PM, see more details of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). If you dont have string dates then you can directly use `date` variable shown above.

Cheers !!